# Unable to open app on heroku. Heroku push successful

Tags: django, heroku

```
2019-05-25T11:36:36.289133+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/ecommerce/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-05-25T11:36:36.289134+00:00 app[web.1]:     import env
2019-05-25T11:36:36.289178+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env'
2019-05-25T11:36:36.289942+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-25 11:36:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-05-25T11:36:36.438624+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-25 11:36:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-05-25T11:36:36.438708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-25 11:36:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-05-25T11:36:36.520758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-25T11:36:36.504539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-05-25T12:23:44.883193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-project-helmy.herokuapp.com request_id=f5cce178-1385-40ef-aa28-1bec8c12d412 fwd="121.7.201.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-25T12:23:45.573689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-project-helmy.herokuapp.com request_id=a6a496e6-5dd6-49cf-91b5-fac3fdff9de2 fwd="121.7.201.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-25T12:28:55.739148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-project-helmy.herokuapp.com request_id=c7f46f87-e1a3-4d6a-8169-15b6c6c94d8e fwd="121.7.201.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-25T12:28:56.174385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-project-helmy.herokuapp.com request_id=4f0b3a7f-84bd-4d93-864e-5299625af45d fwd="121.7.201.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: i tried opening the app on heroku, application error

Comment: what do you think `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env'` means?

Comment: i need to add env to installed apps in settings.py?

Comment: no you need to make sure that `env` is installed in your virtual environment (`pip`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got it to work by using this if os.path.exists('env.py'):
    import env in settings.py

Comment: but isn't it a bit strange that your `env.py` somehow does not exists on your heroku? Either the `import env` was never necessary, or something seems a bit wrong with your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not install certain packages in your virtual environment (`requirements.txt`). One if these modules is [**`env`** [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/env/).

As is specified in the [documentation of *Heroku* on Python dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip):

> To **specify Python package dependencies** on Heroku via `pip`, add a `pip` requirements file named **`requirements.txt` to the root** of your repository.

Here your file will contain `env`, but likely you forgot to specify other packages as well.